# Mesos cluster port opening

Tags: mesos

I want to run mesos cluster on Google Cloud / AWS. Is this a good common practice to allow all instances within cluster to communicate with each others freely without any restriction (white-list firewall for all instance), or we should only allow them communicate via specific ports. I got quite a number of running services and sometimes it's hard to know which port I need to open.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to have a private and a public **security zone** (in AWS/EC2 this would translate to a security group, in GCP/GCE to network policies). Within the private zone all the nodes communicate freely and the public one is pretty much locked down besides the ones you need. Have a look at the [DCOS architecture](https://docs.mesosphere.com/getting-started/dcosarchitecture/) for further details.

The second part of your question relates to essentially a list of well-known ports. We're working on putting together such a list and publish it, soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question about your application needs than mesos. If whatever you run on mesos-slaves don't need to talk to each other, there is no need for slaves to be able to talk to each other for example.

For mesos cluster to work, required routes are

- master(s) -> zookeeper(s)
- slave(s) -> zookeeper(s)
- slave(s) -> master(s)